# Passing objects between UITableViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to implement `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

So far this is what I have in my first UITableViewController:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    secondviewcontroller *vc = [[secondviewcontroller alloc]init];

    BudgetPlan *tempBudget = [self.budgetElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    vc.budgetPlan = tempBudget;
}
```

My second view controller has the ff:

```
// secondviewcontroller.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) BudgetPlan *budgetPlan;


//secondviewcontroller.m

@synthesize budgetPlan = _budgetPlan

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@ was passed with %@",self.budgetPlan.name, self.budgetPlan.amount);

self.budgetName.text = _budgetPlan.name;
    self.amountBudgeted.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", _budgetPlan.amount];
}
```

Unfortunately, the NSLog shows up as nil. Consequently, UILabels budgetName.text and amountBudgeted.text are also empty.

I've set the datasource and delegates to the custom UIViewController which contains the UITableView element (this is not a UITableViewController). It seems like I am passing the object, but it doesn't seem to be passing...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: please don't repost old questions. alter the original http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830343/how-to-pass-objects-between-uitableviews

Comment: Where/how do you alloc (+init?) `budgetPlan` in `secondviewcontroller`? Perhaps try setting `budgetPlan` to something immediately before your NSLog to see if it's the data passthrough?

Comment: try if self.budgetName is still (null) in viewDidAppear.

Comment: I have implemented a lazy instantiation to the budgetPlan via this method:

    -(BudgetPlan *)budgetPlan
    {
        if (_budgetPlan == nil) 
        {
            _budgetPlan = [[BudgetPlan alloc] init];
        }
        return _budgetPlan;
    }

I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. The problem seems to be my use of storyboards. This

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  method seems to only work when not using storyboards.

I answered it by using Segues instead.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

/*
 When a row is selected, the segue creates the detail view controller as the destination.
 Set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
 */

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetailsOfBudget"]) 
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.budgetsTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
        BudgetDetailsViewController *detailsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailsViewController.budget = [self.budgetPlan.budgets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an `budgetPlan` object but in your code you never set the properties `name` and `amount`.

in viewDidLoad you are actually logging exactly these properties, which are still `nil` and `NSLog` logs (null).

```
NSLog(@"%@ was passed with %@",self.budgetPlan.name, self.budgetPlan.amount);
```

You could try logging `budgetPlan` itself. You should get an object memory address.

Comment: I was under the impression that I was passing the budgetPlan that I tapped on in firstviewcontroller... How would I do this?

Comment: well, yes you do as you said. if .name and .amount are set it should actually work. if not you should get "(null) was passed with (null)".
You could try NSLog(@"budgedObject address: %@", budgetObject);
If you still get (null) there is something going on and we need to in vestige further.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try the suggestion above (log out the budgetPlan object itself to see if that is nil).

If it isn't nil, then you'll have to look elsewhere in your code to see why the properties on it are nil.

If it is nil then the problem is your use of viewDidLoad.

You don't know when viewDidLoad will have been called. You've got two options:

```
1. Don't use viewDidLoad to do that - you could use viewWillAppear instead

2. If second view controller is only ever associated with one budget plan, then don't set the property like that but make a custom init method:

    -(id) initWithBudgetPlan:(BudgetPlan *)plan
    {
       if (self = [super init])
       {
         self.budgetPlan = plan;
       }
       return self;
    }
```